# How to not show/remove merge commit in my pull request

Tags: git, github

I have made a Pull request to a repository through origin/some-branch. Now that repo updates and for some reason I had to update my branch. I updated it not via local repo but through website. Now it shows commits like :

1. My commit
2. Other commits as merged xyz

Now I pull this repo to my local repo when I get back. At my local repo I see :
 1. My commit
 2. commit between mine and old version of repo (each individual commit not a merge commit)

Now i have to remove that commit but keep commits of others too.(opensource). How to do that ?

If i squash these commits after me they will be added to mine.

If i remove them will it affect the commit tree of original repo?

Ps . Tried many times and had to reset the branch.

Answer (score 1):

Try instead to rebase your branch on top of the upstream updated branch, with "upstream" being a remote referencing the original repository (which has merged your PR branch)

```
git remote add upstream /url/original/repo
git fetch upstream

git rebase --onto upstream/master firstCommit~..YourBranch
```

Replace "firstCommit" with the oldest commit you want to keep (the ~ will reference the parent of that commit)
Then force push your newly rebased branch.

But it would be better, after that rebase, to push it as a *different* branch, instead of the same one (which was used for a now accepted PR)